# How to find 5 top source port number who sent out most packets in wireshark?

Tags: wireshark

I want to sort captured traffic on #packet sent through ports. How can I filter this in wireshark?

**Edit 1:**

I have captured traffic, I want to find most port sending packet from specific Address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to the `Statistics` menu.
2. Click `Conversations`.
3. Click either the `UDP` or `TCP` tab as appropriate.
4. Click the `Packets A->B` column twice to sort by the number of packets in descending order.
5. The first five rows of the `Port A` column will now show the five source ports with the most packets (and `Address A` the associated IP with each port).

This is using Wireshark 1.12.8.